# Automate using selenium to Validate data displayed

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am currently working on a project which has few Id's in the first screen and depending on the Id selected, user is navigated to second page which displays respective Id's information. All the information displayed is retrieved from SQL database.

Here is my question how can I automate this using Selenium.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How thoroughly have you looked into using Selenium? Automating a single click and verifying data on the next page is on the very basic end of the spectrum when it comes to Selenium. What exactly do you want to automate? Do you want to verify information on the second page? Do you want to just make sure links exist? Is using just the IDE sufficient? Do you need to run this programatically?

Comment: I want to verify data displayed on second page

Comment: Would using just the IDE be sufficient eg, save a suite of tests and run them in just firefox occasionally? Or are you looking to run them from code on different browsers to test compatibility?

Comment: Currently i would run in firefox

Comment: Please send me some steps or you can also send me some link which i can go over

Comment: u can get data from ui and compare the data by getting data from database

Answer (score 0):

If you have a coding background I would suggest writing some basic automated tests with Selenium WebDriver. This will allow you to find elements on the page via their ids, get text from textfields, click on links, and verify that another page has loaded (sounds like the tasks you wish to perform?). You can structure your tests so they run through the main functionality path (eg. go from log in, to main screen, to another screen, testing all functionality along the way) and then you will only have to write a few tests. If you want full automation it is usually better to have specific requirements for your application and write a separate test for each. The Selenium homepage has some good [documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/) with code snippets to get you started, and a simple google search should provide you with several tutorials. Good luck :)

Comment: There can be a bit of a learning curve at first, but the tests are very simple to write once you have done a few.